# dns.count.answers>3 Tshark

Tags: count, dns, tshark

On Tshark;

I am trying to run this command "tshark -r /root/Desktop/a.pcap -T fields -e "dns.count.answers>3"" however I always see; " (process:2009): WARNING : 'dns.count.answers>3' isn't a valid field! tshark: Some fields aren't valid"

Do you have any idea about how can I see "dns.count.answers>3" on tshark and then output it as a cvs. file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[Tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)'s `-e` option expects a *field* as an argument; however, "`dns.count.answers>3`" isn't a field but a *display filter*.  Display filters are specified using the `-Y` option.

What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
tshark -r /root/Desktop/a.pcap -Y "dns.count.answers > 3" -T fields -e dns.count.answers
```

Comment: I really confused because I am trying to save it and  when I try "tshark -r /root/Desktop/a.pcap -T fields -e ip.dst -E header=y -E separator=, >/root/Desktop/em.csv" it saves successfully and I can see ip numbers. It is ok. So according to this part I have a permission to write root/Desktop.
However, when I try "tshark -r /root/Desktop/a.pcap -T fields -e dns.count.answers -Y "dns.count.answers > 3" -E header=y -E separator=, >/root/Desktop/em.csv"  the file is saved but it is empty.
Also without "> /root/Desktop/x.csv" it works and I can see the numbers.

Comment: if you have any idea please let me know :)

Comment: Do you think it is right, "tshark -r /root/Desktop/a.pcap -T fields -e ip.dst -E header=y -E separator=, >/root/Desktop/em.csv"